# I'm new to C, and this segmentation fault stuff is killing me

Tags: c, pointers, memory, segmentation-fault, malloc

I am new to c, and I am hitting the web hard, soaking up resources to help learn.

I am starting off with a simple command prompt type deal, and even this is giving me difficulties! I am trying my best to learn pointers, but the idea is hard to grasp for me, so here is the code that is giving me trouble. I hope that the answers to this troublesome code will help enlighten me on the syntax of pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "login.h"
#include "help.h"
#include <malloc.h>

main()
{
if(login())                /* Login runs fine. After the imported */ 
{                          /*login code runs, it takes me to the main screen */
    int prac;          /* (printf("Type help for a list of commands")) i input*/
    char inpt[255];    /* help, the imported help screen runs,then the core 
    int *ptr;          /*dumps. oh and i know the malloc() syntax is wront*/
    malloc(255) == ptr;   /*that's just the last thing i tried before i posted*/

    *ptr == printf("Continuing Program...\n\n");
    printf("---Type Help For a List of Commands----\n");
    gets(inpt);
    if (strcmp(inpt, help) == 1)
    {
        help();
        goto *ptr;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't compile, let alone segfault. A book is your best friend.

Comment: If you want to know why some code has a problem, then show that exact code -- not something else you attempted afterward.

Comment: It would help if you explained what you expected this code to do. Some of the lines of code are utterly baffling, like `malloc(255) == ptr;` and `*ptr == printf("Continuing Program...\n\n");`. It's hard to imagine what you expected these to do.

Comment: @LucDanton this is the exact code O.O

Comment: I'd suggest a copy of Kernighan and Ritchie. It has taught a lot of people to program in C.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz the malloc, as i said, was wrong, and the last attempt at a last ditch effort. as for the *ptr statement... again, very new ;)

Comment: But a last ditch effort to do what? It's really hard to help you if we don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Fred thank you! i will be sure to check it out. i need a good printed resource to read up on when away from the laptop.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i just realized what it is you meant. -_- i was attempting to run the "help" prom[t. then return to the main screen, or, at this time, the printf("Continuing Program...\n\n") line. i apologize for the lack of clarity

Comment: I think the confusion is that a label "points" to a location in code, and a pointer also "points" to things.   He was trying to set a pointer at the start of the printf he could then later "goto" to

Comment: @KeithNicholas precisely!

Comment: See my answer for one way of handling it..... you could do it with a label and a goto also, but I couldn't bring myself to write code that uses gotos ;)

Comment: @KeithNicholas hey, this isn't exactly going to a distributed code, more one to expand and study. thank you very much for your solution, it makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just revised to do what I think you want, I'm assuming you want to get help,  then loop around and get another command from the user.

```
int prac;          
char inpt[255];    
bool quit = false;
while(!quit)
{
printf("Continuing Program...\n\n");
printf("---Type Help For a List of Commands----\n");
gets(inpt);
if (strcmp(inpt, "help") == 0)
{
    help();     
}
if (strcmp(inpt, "quit") == 0)
{
    quit = true;
}

}
```

pointers aren't used with goto,  while similar in concept to labels,  in reality they are quite different in terms of how the language works.

Comment: thats exactly what i needed actually! thank you, very much. this was very helpful!

Answer (score 4):

You may want to review basic C.

This is a comparison, not an assignment.  The statement leaks memory but has no other effect.

```
malloc(255) == ptr;
```

This dereferences an uninitialized variable, and compares it with the result code of `printf()`.  Most people just ignore the result of `printf()`.  However, since `ptr` is uninitialized, this will *at best* crash your program with a segmentation fault, and might do something worse.

```
*ptr == printf("Continuing Program...\n\n");
```

This compares a string against a function.  This will probably not crash on most systems, but it's wrong either way.

```
strcmp(inpt, help)
```

This is nonsense, and shouldn't compile.  You can only `goto` a label, and `*ptr` is not a label.

```
goto *ptr;
```

Comment: thank you! the malloc statement was a last ditch effort, throwing it at the wall and hoping something would stick. thank you for being nice to the noob :P

Comment: @MitchellGrayEdwards: If you "throw things against the wall and hope they stick", you will always have problems with segmentation faults, and worse.